# How many nucleotides are there in the LMO1?

Tags: dna

Dr Maris at CHOP has linked the cause of high-risk neuroblastoma to a common SNP in  LMO1. How many nucleotides are there in the LMO1 gene?

Answer (score 1):

1274bp

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NM_002315.1

If you need to know gene size and are confused w search results, search for gene name + "cDNA"

Comment: Technically, this is the mRNA, not the gene itself.

Comment: mRNA has u's not t, it's cDNA, but yes it represents the transcript.

Comment: right, that's what I meant :)